# How to make user notice a new link

Tags: jquery, plugins

is there a jquery plugin (or a js snippet) that makes a sentence sliding from one side to the other?

For example when i have a sentence of five words to, to be possible for me to declare a 300px width box and make the sentence inside it sliding from right to left and when it finish to start again.

or a flash plugin?

The issue is that i have a new link (that link to important pdf document) inside my page and i want to find a way to make the user notice it when he visits my site. So i thought i can put gif next to the link that flashes "new" and also put the plugin that i asked you on top right of the page that says there is a new "pdf".

Have anyone any idea of how i should do it? is anyone aware of any other technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a [built-in `animate` function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). You could use that to animate your new link. Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/na3Xb/

Comment: that is a good thought. it gives me the freedom to manipulate it better. and also i guess i have no problem with html5

Answer (score 0):

You can use this "marquee" tag of HTML

demo : http://www.mountaindragon.com/html/marquee.htm

Use this code if you want effect like marquee tag using Jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/zpwVq/

Comment: `<marquee>` is obsolete in HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html and therefore probably not the most future-proof choice

Comment: @PareshBalar yes something like that. But i search for a jquery plugin because it is going to be better designed and not obsolete in HTML5.Correct? If you have in mind any other idea of how to make a person notice the new link just give me.

Comment: Marquee is perfect if you're trying to recreate that coveted '96 feel on your website. For best results use it with Comic Sans and populate any unfinished pages with an animated gif of a dumper truck. ;)

Comment: My personal suggestion is to use marquee tag only..its light and simple to use.. plugins makes load..

Comment: @Mr_Chimp it is sth temporaly anyway. marquee is sth that i didn't know. But i think in some cases you can create sth really fancy that way. Of course with some styling and with the Comic Sans font that i also like and use.